# Login app and Streamreader on WindowsForms (c#)

Tags: c#

even though I've been using this site in order to learn and solve some questions, this is my very first time asking one.

I'm working on a simple login application that should read 2 text files (one with usernames, the other with passwords) and then compare them to the text written in their respective textboxes.

```
    string user, pass;
    string pathtouser = @"C:\Users.txt";/*Both are
                                         paths */
    string pathtopass = @"C:\Pass.txt";

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    Login logeo = new Login();
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        logeo.openFile();
    }
    private void loginbutt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader Read = new StreamReader(pathtouser);
        StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(pathtopass);
        user = Read.ReadToEnd();
        pass = Reader.ReadToEnd();
        //Here we read the textfiles and add the string to the variables (user and pass)

        if (Usertext.Text == user && passtext.Text == pass)
        {
            testing test = new testing();
            test.Show();
        }//New window it should open if username and password inserted in the textboxes are correct.
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User or password is incorrect. Please verify!!", "WARNING!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        }//Denies access and shows a warning.
```

It works well... Only validating the first line. 
Problem is, that I have around two more users and passwords allocated on the text files that are not read, therefore I'm unable to log-in using those.

A friend of mine has suggested that I should exploit the ASCII code in order to find the whole string containing the desired usernames and passwords and using a for loop.

As a beginner, is there a better way to do this? (I've got to learn about arrays as well)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like...

```
List<string> users = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(pathtouser));
List<string> passwords = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(pathtopass));
int index = users.IndexOf(Usertext.Text);
if (index != -1 && index < passwords.Count)
{
    if (passtext.Text == passwords[index])
    {
        testing test = new testing();
        test.Show();
        return;
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("User or password is incorrect. Please verify!!", "WARNING!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to play around with it in order to do as I desired, but I could finally test it with different users and passwords and works very well! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also read each line from the Users.txt and compare the password saved at that respective position in your Pass.txt file. So being a beginner you can first try to understand the following code and proceed in improving them later:

```
int lineCounter = 0;
string user;
List<string> passwords = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(pathtopass));//store passwords in a List array

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\Users.txt");
while((user = file.ReadLine()) != null)//this will read each line at a time till it reaches the end of the file
{
   if(Usertext.Text == user)//check for the user
   {
   try{
        if (passtext.Text == passwords[lineCounter])//check for the password stored in the respective line in the Password.txt
        {
            //do your thing-->
            testing test = new testing();
            test.Show();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User or password is incorrect. Please verify!!", "WARNING!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        }//Denies access and shows a warning.
    }
    catch(Exception frog)//catch any exception which might arise here
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: "+frog.Message.ToString());
    }
   }
   lineCounter++;//increment the counter to fetch the next index
}

file.Close();//close the file after reading is complete
```

This example uses ReadLine (reading each line) of StreamReader and at the same time also uses List array to read all lines and outputs it.